# having issue to display then data in angularjs via json array

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, json

I try to display data in angularjs via json data array but can't figure out or fix the issue when i return the json data from my php file it give me result

```
["{name:'abc', age:19}","{name:'xyz', age:21}"]
```

but its not working because in Angular i need data in format something like this

```
[{name:'abc', age:19},{name:'xyz', age:21}]
```

now issue is i can't figure out how can i rearrange this array format i tried `JSON.parse()` but its not working

its my php code

```
if($xml->product) {

foreach ($xml->product as $node ){

    $productName = $node->name;
    $productID = $node->productID;
    $productPrice = $node->price;
    $productURL = $node->imageURL;
    $productCat = $node->categories->category;

    //$product = "{name: '".$productName."', productid: '".$productID."' }";
      $product = array("name"=> "".$productName."", "productid"=> "".$productID."");

    array_push($data1, $product);

}} else {
echo "error!"; } print json_encode($data1);
```

problem fixed actually i am passing string in array and then encode with json it give me this double quote issue. now what i fix is change string in array and passed by json it automatically convert these array in object :)

Comment: It's the issue with json format post your php code

Comment: So basically you are getting an array of objects.. Just parse the objects.?

Comment: Are you willing to manipulate the data in angular at all? Because if you are then all you need to do is use JSON.parse() on each string in your list

Comment: if you can see the first array is a valid JSON format and the second array is not a valid JSON format so if you want to display a data JSON.parse() will help you..!!

Comment: yes i use JSON.parse() but its not working in angularjs

Comment: For some very weird reasons, JSON.parse on the first array is giving an error on the console for me..

Comment: Your PHP should be returning: [{
 "name": "abc",
 "age": 19
}, {
 "name": "xyz",
 "age": 21
}] If you need help with spitting out the correct JSON, post the PHP code that generates it.

Comment: Try with  $product = '{"name": "'.$productName.'","productid: "'.$productID.'" }';

Comment: not working same result!

Comment: any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

its fixed by changing string into array

```
 $product = "{name: '".$productName."', productid: '".$productID."' }";
```

replace with this

```
$product = array("name"=> "".$productName."", "productid"=> "".$productID."");
```